# W3 Schools Modal Example only working on Chrome Debug mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am following W3 schools tutorial on creating a modal.  The solution works fine when I am in debug mode and step through the code, but it is not working when not in debug mode.  The only difference between the demo on W3 and my code is that I am applying the HTML and CSS dynamically on the page load via Javascript using the JQuery library.  My browser is Google Chrome (53.0.2785.143)

**HTML applied through JS:**

```
sHTML += '<div id="myModal" class="modal">';
sHTML += '<div class="modal-content"><p>some text in modal</p></div>';
sHTML += '</div>';
$("Body").append( sHTML );
```

**CSS applied through JS:**

```
$(".modal").css({"display":"none","position":"fixed","z-index":"1","padding-top":"100px","left":"0","top":"0","width":"100%","height":"100%","overflow":"auto","background-color":"rgb(0,0,0)","background-color":"rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"});
```

**Modal Action:**

```
$("#documentLink").on('click', function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    modal.style.display = "block";

    //processing logic...

    //processing finished.

    modal.style.display = "none";
});
```

**W3 Link to Example:**
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: Could you perhaps make this in a fiddle? It should be a simple answer but it's hard to tell where your JS is being called 'cause I can't see the actual blocks.

Comment: Agreed. Started to create a fiddle myself, but too much plumbing and guessing to get your snippets to function without knowing the rest of your code.

Comment: I replicated my code to JS Fiddle.  This is working properly in JSFiddle, its just not working in my actual solution.  

https://jsfiddle.net/cjpicc11/0jeamyzc/15/#&togetherjs=ADNObiMCFS

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your code.You coded modal.style.display = "block"; and modal.style.display = "none"; on click of same ID "documentLink". In debug mode you will go step by step,So modal is coming up fine in debug mode.

Try to write close function in other span something like below

```
 btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```